# Do opensource rootkits exist for Android?

Tags: android

I've been reading a few articles lately that talk about Android botnets which rely on security flaws in old Android versions to get root access and take over the phone.

Obviously this is pretty bad from a risk perspective, as plenty of Android's are running on outdated versions. I know there are individual exploits like those on the exploit database https://www.exploit-db.com/, but I'm interested in evidence of a rootkit that leverages several known vulnerabilities to target multiple different devices and/or versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I suspect there are also others that may be more feature-rich. Searches for these in other languages may also be useful for finding others.

https://github.com/hiteshd/Android-Rootkit

Although not technically open source you may want to look at the Hacking Team dump that was in the news a while back some of the code from that may be of interest to you.

https://github.com/hackedteam?tab=repositories